# Arrays with numpy in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I know that instead of arrays in Python we have lists. But I am using the numpy import.

I have created a function to check gender based upon a Swedish Social security number.

Based upon 10 digits and if the eighth digit is even, it's a female, otherwise a male.

When I run the function, I get the error of:

> line 11, in ssnCheckGender
> if ssn[8] % 2 == 0: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

This is my code with the example input of 9202205078, should be a male:

```
import numpy as np

def ssnCheckGender():
    ssn = np.array([])

    ssn = int(input("Input SSN, 10 digits: "))

    if ssn[8] % 2 == 0:
        print(f"The {ssn} is a female")
    else:
        print(f"The {ssn} is a male")


ssnCheckGender()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: ``ssn = int(...`` assigns a *single* integer to ``ssn``. It does not matter that ``ssn`` referred to a value of a different type before.

Comment: I hope you did not provide real ssn ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't take the input as `int` but as a `string` with string, you can get the position values easily.
once you get the position values i.e `ssn[7]` then cast to int.

> note that the index starts from 0 so the index of the 8th element will be 7.

```
def ssnCheckGender():

    ssn = str(input("Input SSN, 10 digits: "))

    if int(ssn[7]) % 2 == 0:
        print(f"The {ssn} is a female")
    else:
        print(f"The {ssn} is a male")


ssnCheckGender()
```

output : for eg: 9202205078

```
Input SSN, 10 digits: 9202205078
The 9202205078 is a female
```

Comment: Thanks :) So I didn't need to use the numpy import for this then. But I do understand the logic behind taking the input as string and then, then casting it to int. 
But I have to use index of 8, if I start the index at 0, its the ninth digit to be checked.

Comment: @user2371684 no, you don't need to use the numpy. you'll get the 8th element with the 7th index. in the above eg; `9202205078` the 8th element is `0`  whose index will be `7` (element-1), since it starts from `0`.